# CSS sprite vs Image during browser zoom

Tags: html, css

I have many small icons in my website. Instead of loading all of them independently, I am thinking of using CSS sprites due to performance gain.

Consider the following code

```
<div style="width: 24px; height: 24px;background: url('img.png') -10px -10px;"></div>
```

vs

```
<img src="css-sprites.png" style="width: 24px;height: 24px;">
```

As expected, both gives same result. When loading as an image (second case), if I  keep resolution of actual image a higher value, say 128*128, and using 24*24 for display, I am getting better resolution even when we zoom the page in browser (tested in mozilla).

But when using css sprites, since I have to keep the same display resolution in the sprite, the image gets blurred when zooming.

Is this expected behavior or am i doing something wrong? Is there any way to overcome this issue when using css sprites?

I do not have much experience with html and first time going to use css sprites. Please help.

Edit: also, many posts I could see in internet about cross-browser issues while zooming. Is this some point of concern even now?

Comment: Tell me, do your icons all one colored?

Comment: two colors, some in white and some in black

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your sprite size is 200x200 px, and you want to get better resolution by zooming - make you `background-size: 100px 100px;`. So if you will zoom to 200% - the quality of you image will still be good. Obviously, your sprite image should be twice bigger the size you are going to use on your website. To avoid problems - do not mix `%` and `px` or any other different units in one `background-size`. Use only `px` in your case and everything will work just fine.

Summarizing. Make sprite twice bigger, set `background-size` twice smaller the size of sprite image. Tested it in Chrome and FF. Works fine on zooming.

If you are familiar with `svg` files - try to do your own vector font (for icons) using http://fontastic.me/. No scaling issues will disturb you. You can set size by `font-size` and make them any color by `color` in CSS, like a text.

Comment: thanks, this look great. However, whether  background-size is cross browser ? there are many posts over issues while using background-size

Comment: background size is quite old and native in all browsers. To avoid problems - do not mix **%** and **px** or any other different units in one `background-size`. Use only **px** in your case and everything will work just fine. And look for vector icons. I insure you - it will be the best expirience.

Comment: but svgs have disadvantages also right? lot of debates over png vs svg. can scale without losing clarity but additional processing and more memory?

Comment: Processing memory for svg - yes, adding a little. But with your 4 icons nobody will see a the difference in performance. Although size of svg is times smaller then jpg or png. svg is native even for IE. and. if you’ll convert it using fontastic - it will be just a webfont. One color icon svg is the best choice. On any screen dpi